# unset particular row in multidimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, multidimensional-array

I am creating a online shopping website in php. In the add to cart process a user adds the product details and quantity in the session using the multidimensional array.

If the user want to remove a particular product from the cart list they can remove it using the (X)mark. 
I have the following array stucture:

```
array (size=8)

'id' => 
    array (size=4)

      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '2' (length=1)

  'pwidth' => 
    array (size=4)

      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => string '9' (length=1)
      3 => string '5' (length=1)

  'pheight' => 
    array (size=4)

      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => string '10' (length=2)
      3 => string '6' (length=1)

  'pdepth' => 
    array (size=4)

      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
      2 => string '11' (length=2)
      3 => string '7' (length=1)

  'handel' => 
    array (size=4)

      0 => string 'no' (length=2)
      1 => string 'no' (length=2)
      2 => string 'yes' (length=3)
      3 => string 'no' (length=2)

  'quantity' => 
    array (size=4)

      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      1 => string '8' (length=1)
      2 => string '12' (length=2)
      3 => string '8' (length=1)

  'add' => 
    array (size=4)

      0 => string 'Add to Cart' (length=11)
      1 => string 'Add to Cart' (length=11)
      2 => string 'Add to Cart' (length=11)
      3 => string 'Add to Cart' (length=11)

  'count' => int 4
```

If the user removes a product from the array, the rest of the list should automatically align from the top. please help me to know the concept. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you click your (X) mark to delete/remove product from cart, at that time you can get that product's array key. Now you know that this key is unique as (i hope you are using the same key to store that products data in all arrays) in all other arrays i.e. `id`,`pwidth`, etc.., You can `unset($key)` that key from all the arrays and than can do `array_values($array)` to reindex the arrays.